# MBProgressHUD unable to change text if shown on window

Tags: ios, uikit, uiapplication, mbprogresshud

I am using a MBProgressHUD and I need to show it on window as I want to add many full screen views. I set HUD with a text and when i change the text later, its not changing the text. HUD is a retained property of a singleton class. When i show it on view it allow me to do so. But i need to do it with window.

```
 _HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:_HUD];
    _HUD.delegate=self;
 _HUD.labelText =HUD_TEXT_LOADING;
 _HUD.detailsLabelText =HUD_TEXT_PLEASE_WAIT;
    [_HUD show:YES];
```

This is how i am changing the text

```
 -(void) changeHUDText:(NSString*)text andDetailText:(NSString*) detailText
{
if (_HUD) {
    if (text)
        _HUD.labelText=text;

    if (detailText)
        _HUD.detailsLabelText=detailText;
}
}
```

Comment: try to initialize _HUD in viewDidLoad]

Comment: cant do that i have to do behind a method.

Answer (score 2):

You should just add this method to the header file of MBProgressHud:

```
+ (MB_INSTANCETYPE)showHUDAddedTo:(UIView *)view withText:(NSString *)text;
```

And implement it in the .m file as follows:

```
+ (MB_INSTANCETYPE)showHUDAddedTo:(UIView *)view withText:(NSString *)text
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [[self alloc] initWithView:view];
    hud.labelText = text;
    [view addSubview:hud];
    [hud show:YES];
    return MB_AUTORELEASE(hud);
}
```

and call it wherever you want like:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view withText:@"Loading..."];
```